# Dijit: Closing Multiple Tabs

Tags: dojo

Say I have the following Dijit tabs in a tab container:

```
tab_1
tab_dave
tab_2
tab_3
...
tab_n
```

How could I close all tabs apart from `tab_dave`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it would be to loop through all the children, removing the ones without that particular name or id.

```
function closeAllBut(containerId, tabId)
{
    var tc = dijit.byId(containerId),
        tabs = tc.getChildren();

    for(var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++)
    {
        if(tabs[i].id != tabId) tc.removeChild(tabs[i]);
    }
}
```

Seems quite slow though, it'd be nice if there was a cleaner way (so don't accept my answer! :) )

Answer (score 2):

to query with dojo check *dojo.query*
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/query.html

Query on element type or classname or whatever, provide second parameter for

```
dojo.forEach(dojo.query(".tabs", "containerId"), 
    function(closeTab) {
        //doStuff
    }
);
```

But, if there are a lot of tabs you could destroy(recursive) the entire tabContainer and build a new one with just 1 element.